# What is the best type to store multidimensional data type in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

what is the best type to store data from csv format file, where is 150k records(lines) where each line has 9 columns(fields). After initialize my type with these data i need to do some operations on it, like add record in specified line, or add/change some data in some field. Also i need to compare data between themselves. Thank for help!

Comment: Create your own class?

Comment: "Best" by what measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best type to use is an ArrayList of a domain object. The domain object has 9 properties.

In other words: don't make it generic, make it specific for your problem. Then your code will be more readable and type-safety helps you when you create the functionality.